# How to Confirm that a Pointer Has Been Reassigned to a New Address - Pointers to Constant Characters

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to learn C++ and I am having some issues understanding why my pointer isn't displaying the expected address value after being reassigned to a new character variable.

In the provided code, I would have expected that

```
pointer_to_const = &c;
```

display a new address value from when it was assigned to character variable `b`

When I run the code shown below, I get this;

```
-------Constant Pointer---------(works as expected)
Constant pointer a has an address of: 0x7ff7b1bc749f and value of: a
Constant pointer a has an address of: 0x7ff7b1bc749f and a new value of: x

--------Pointer to Const--------(not sure why I don't get a new address for c)
Pointer to const has an    address of: 0x7ff7b1bc7488 and value of: b
Pointer to const has a new address of: 0x7ff7b1bc7488 and value of: c


--------Pointer to Const--(**CORRECTED OUTPUT BASED ON USER FEEDBACK**)
Pointer to const has an address of: 0x7ff7b54a844e and value of: b
Pointer to const has a new address of: 0x7ff7b54a844d and value of: c
```

The Constant Pointer section gives me the results I expect, but a couple of things are throwing me off with the Pointer to Const section below.

After setting `pointer_to_const = &c` I don’t understand why I don’t see a new address for **pointer_to_const** when I display it with `cout`. Doesn’t `c` have a unique address?

Also, in the Pointer to Const section I can display `&pointer_to_const` with `cout`, but I can’t properly display `&b`, or `&c` directly with `cout`.

I am pretty much following the C version of this and I am trying to get it to work in C++ as part of the overall learning process.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egvGq3WSF9Y](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';
  
    // Constant Pointer 
    std::cout << "-------Constant Pointer---------" << std::endl;
    char *const constant_pointer = &a;
    std::cout << "Constant pointer a has an address of: " << static_cast<void*>(constant_pointer) << " and value of: " << *constant_pointer << std::endl;
    *constant_pointer = 'x';
    std::cout << "Constant pointer a has an address of: " << static_cast<void*>(constant_pointer) << " and a new value of: " << *constant_pointer << std::endl;

     // Pointer to Const 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------Pointer to Const--------" << std::endl; 
    const char *pointer_to_const = &b;
    // **Edit** - section updated to properly display address pointed to by pointer_to_const 
    std::cout << "Pointer to const has an address of: " << static_cast<const void*>(pointer_to_const) << " and value of: " << *pointer_to_const << std::endl;
    pointer_to_const = &c;
    std::cout << "Pointer to const has a new address of: " << static_cast<const void*>(pointer_to_const) << " and value of: " << *pointer_to_const << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `&pointer_to_const` -- This is the address of the pointer, not the value of the pointer.  This cannot change.  Pointers must live somewhere, just like any other variable, and all you're doing here is printing the address of the pointer.

Comment: You should be aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) as well as [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - read up on both. Also, the address of where a pointer variable is stored in memory is not the same as the value of the pointer.

Comment: I'm curious why you correctly did `static_cast<void*>(constant_pointer)` when you wanted to point out the value of `constant_pointer` but you switched it up to `&pointer_to_const` instead of `static_cast<const void*>(pointer_to_const)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - thanks for clarifying the inherent address of the pointer, pointer_to_const, vs the address that the pointer is holding

Comment: @NathanPierson - I originally tried static_cast<void*> but got compilation errors I didn't know how to resolve; thanks for showing me the proper way to using casting for the datatype at hand in order to print the address of the var

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I couldn't quite follow what you were getting at with the as-if rule and undefined behavior in relation to my OP; perhaps it will sink in as I learn more about C++

Answer (score 1):

When writing `&pointer_to_const`, you are getting the address of the pointer. This is not the same as the address that the pointer contains/is pointing to.

```
&pointer_to_const //address of the pointer
pointer_to_const  //content of the pointer (i.e. an address of another variable)
*pointer_to_const //content of the variable that the pointer points to
```

Comment: Admittedly as a novice to using C++, I didn't think about the differences between the first 2 pointer explanations that you give. Crystal clear now.